# Criação de Query com Union ALL para juntar tabelas com indexação pelo nome da tabela

Tags: php, mysql, sql, zend

Tem um problema que fizeram em um banco de dados, que preciso resolver temporariamente, criaram várias tabelas com índice no nome da tabela, onde o sistema cria uma tabela nova a cada usuário novo... (Isso foi mal feito), provavelmente o desenvolvedor criou esse novo problema, para atender um problema de lentidão, e provavelmente ele nunca ouviu falar em índices de tabelas, entretanto, eu tenho que fazer uma solução temporária, para posteriormente corrigir o banco de dados. Então estou tentando resolver isso através do código, ocorre que estou tendo dificuldade para implementar uma query, estou usando Zend Framework 1.12.20.

Esta é o Model do Dao:

```
class Application_Model_Dao_DataSchoolMembers
{

    private $dbTable;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->dbTable = new Application_Model_DbTable_SchoolsMembers();
        $this->dbTable->getDefaultAdapter()->setFetchMode(Zend_Db::FETCH_OBJ);
    } 

    public function getDataTableMembers()
        {
            $selectTopTables = $this->dbTable->select()
                ->setIntegrityCheck(false);
            $selectTopTables->from(array('tb' => 'information_schema.tables'),
                array(
                    'first_number' => 'CONVERT(REPLACE(REPLACE(table_name, "School_",""),"_members",""), UNSIGNED)'
                ));

            $selectTopTables->where('tb.table_name LIKE ? ','%School_%');
            $selectTopTables->where('tb.table_name LIKE ? ','%_members%');
            $selectTopTables->order(array('first_number ASC'));
            $v= $selectTopTables->assemble();
            print_r($v);
            $data = $this->getAllDados($selectTopTables);

            return $data;
        }

        public function getMemberByFilter(array $param = array())
        {
            $dataTables = $this->getDataTableMembers();

            $parseSql = array();

            if (!empty($dataTables)) {
                foreach ($dataTables as $key => $value) {
                    $parseSql[] = 'Select ID, user_id, user_type from School_' . $value['first_number'] . '_members';
                }
                $sql = '('.implode(' UNION ALL ', $parseSql).')';

            $select = $this->dbTable->select()
                ->setIntegrityCheck(false)
                ->from(new Zend_Db_Expr($sql).' AS mb',
                array(
                    'mb.ID',
                    'mb.user_id',
                    'mb.user_type'
                ));

                if (isset($param['user_id'])) {
    //                $w[] = 'mb.user_id = ? ';
    //                $val[] = $param['user_id'];
                   $select->where('mb.user_id = ? ', $param['user_id']);
                }
                if (isset($param['id'])) {
    //                $w[] = 'mb.ID = ? ';
    //                $val[] = $param['id'];
                     $select->where('mb.ID = ? ', $param['id']);
                }
                if (isset($param['user_type'])) {
    //                $w[] = 'mb.user_type = ? ';
    //                $val[] = $param['user_type'];
                    $select->where('mb.user_type = ? ', $param['user_type']);
                }

                $select->group( array(
                    'mb.ID',
                    'mb.user_id',
                    'mb.user_type'
                ))->assemble();
                var_dump($select); die();

                return $this->getAllDados($select);
            }
        }
}
```

A SQL do método: `getMemberByFilter()` deveria ficar assim:

```
SELECT mb.ID, mb.user_id, mb.user_type FROM (
  Select ID, user_id, user_type from School_1_members
  UNION ALL 
  Select ID, user_id, user_type
  from School_2_members 
  UNION ALL 
  Select ID, user_id, user_type from School_3_members 
   UNION ALL Select ID, user_id, user_type 
  from School_3_members
) as mb
WHERE mb.user_id = ? 
  group by mb.ID, 
  mb.user_id, 
  mb.user_type
```

Mas não está acontecendo isso, está dando erro.

As tabelas são basicamente assim:

```
CREATE TABLE `School_1_members` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `user_type` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `data` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=394 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

CREATE TABLE `School_2_members` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `user_type` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `data` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=394 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

CREATE TABLE `School_3_members` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `user_type` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `data` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=394 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

Também tentei outra alternativa, que era criar uma view, ou uma procedure no banco de dados, para minimizar o problema, fazendo somente uma consulta direta:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW School_X_Members AS (

/* aqui viria a consulta */

);

SET @resultQuery = NULL;


SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(
    DISTINCT
    CONCAT('SELECT ID, user_id, user_type FROM ', table_name)
    SEPARATOR '\r\nUNION ALL\r\n'
  )
INTO
  @resultQuery
FROM
  information_schema.tables as tb
WHERE (tb.table_name LIKE '%School_%' ) AND (tb.table_name LIKE '%_members%' ) order by 
CONVERT(REPLACE(REPLACE(table_name, "School_",""),"_members",""), UNSIGNED);


SELECT @resultQuery;
```

Só que não estou conseguindo fazer isso funcionar, alguém poderia me ajudar nisso, obrigado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O jeito que eu fiz funcionou, só tive que mudar essa linha:

```
 $select = $this->dbTable->select()
                ->setIntegrityCheck(false)
                ->from(new Zend_Db_Expr($sql).' AS mb',
                array(
                    'mb.ID',
                    'mb.user_id',
                    'mb.user_type'
                ));
```

para:

```
 $select = $this->dbTable->select()
                ->setIntegrityCheck(false)
                ->from(array('mb' => new Zend_Db_Expr($sql)),
                array(
                    'mb.ID',
                    'mb.user_id',
                    'mb.user_type'
                ));
```

Answer (score 0):

Boa tarde Ivan, segue uma sugestão.

```
<?php
$conn = new mysqli('host', 'user', 'password', 'database');
$queryTables = "select * from information_schema.tables where TABLE_NAME like 'School_%_members'";
$result = $conn->query($queryTables);

$query = "SELECT mb.ID, mb.user_id, mb.user_type FROM (\n";
$delimiter = "UNION ALL ";

while ($row = $result->fetch_object()) {
    $query .= "Select ID, user_id, user_type from {$row->TABLE_NAME}\n{$delimiter}";
}

$query = substr($query, 0, strlen($query) - strlen($delimiter))
. ") as mb\n"
. "WHERE mb.user_id = 1\n";

echo $query;
```

Este exemplo monta a sua query com os `UNION ALL` dinâmicos, extraídos do *Information Schema*.

Todo o seu Model eu ignorei, tentei focar no SQL...

E também me parece desnecessário usar a cláusula `GROUP BY` porque você não está fazendo sum(), nem count(), etc, me parece que você só quer recuperar os registros das N tabelas-irmãs, então veja que no meu exemplo deixei de fora o agrupamento.

Sugiro usar apenas `UNION ALL` ou `UNION`, não precisa agrupar pelo que entendi... A diferença entre os dois é que UNION ALL retorna registros duplicados enquanto que UNION não.

No fim da query tem o parâmetro do user_id que utilizei 1, e para testar aqui eu criei as 3 tabelas conforme o seu SQL e inseri os registros assim:

```
insert into School_1_members (user_id, user_type, data) values ('1', 'customer', 'my data customer');
insert into School_1_members (user_id, user_type, data) values ('2', 'customer', 'another data');
insert into School_1_members (user_id, user_type, data) values ('3', 'vendor', 'vendor data');
insert into School_2_members (user_id, user_type, data) values ('1', 'customer', 'my data customer');
insert into School_2_members (user_id, user_type, data) values ('2', 'customer', 'another data');
insert into School_2_members (user_id, user_type, data) values ('3', 'vendor', 'vendor data');
insert into School_3_members (user_id, user_type, data) values ('1', 'customer', 'my data customer');
insert into School_3_members (user_id, user_type, data) values ('2', 'customer', 'another data');
insert into School_3_members (user_id, user_type, data) values ('3', 'vendor', 'vendor data');
```

Comment: Obrigado pela dica.